# how to increase Acuracy of pocketsphinx

Tags: ros, audio, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone i am using pocketsphinx for quite a time now and the accuracy of the model is not satisfactory. can any one please tell me how can i improve the accuracy of pocketsphinx. and also i have indian speaking accent does that also affect to the accuracy of the model

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49071/how-to-increase-acuracy-of-pocketsphinx/) by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-11-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on 2012-11-27**:
so is there any way that i can improve its accuracy

**Comment by [Loy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1830/loy/) on 2012-11-28**:
Not that I know of, besides retraining pocketsphinx. I know next to nothing about its innards, but I can imagine that for a different accent, be it Indian, Dutch or whatever, you need a different language model, with different HMM-probabilities or something like that. This is just a guess though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my experience, PocketSphinx works best on an american accent. This makes sense as it was probably trained on such voices.

---

Originally posted by [Loy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1830/loy/) with karma: 141 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1